# How to add the bash and shell script directory path in gradle build script?

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, build.gradle

I want to add the path of a directory which contains the multiple scripts for windows and linux in my build.gradle script.
Currently i am defining the task like this and its working fine.

```
task initdb(type: Exec){
    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'My_CONF\\pgdb\\initdb.cmd'
    } else {
        commandLine 'My_CONF/pgdb/initdb.sh'
    }
}
```

But I want to define this task as-

```
task initdb(type: Exec){
    if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'initdb.cmd'
    } else {
        commandLine 'initdb.sh'
    }
}
```

These scripts also uses the another scripts which is in My_CONF\pgdb directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the `workingDir` property of the task with type `Exec`, which is defaults to the build script root dir. Take a look at the documentation about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:workingDir).

Comment: @anandmishra you're welcome) of it was helpfull, you may accept and upvote the answer